# is it possible to use one yaml file for build and release?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I want to create one yaml file which will build and release.  Is this possible?
I have a repo in Github and currently have a build yaml file in a pipeline. Currently there is a build pipeline separate and the release is then executed via Azure devops releases. I want to  include both build and release in one yaml file but when i try to do this I cant seem to access files required from the build?

eg I have some terraform tf files in a directory on github which i need to execute terraform on. Despite terraform installing ok in the yaml file it cant find the tf files ? I thought the repo which includes the tf files gets copied to the build workstation but i cant see them there

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to use one yaml file for build and release?

Short answer is Yes, I don't see any reason you shouldn't be able to do what you're wanting.

> I thought the repo which includes the tf files gets copied to the build workstation but i cant see them there

I think we need more details about why you think that. Pipelines have various (hard to figure out) rules about what you have to do to "checkout" or pull various repos into your agent's working folder and where those repos get copied to, so we'd need to know more about what you're actually doing in your script, what your checkout steps are reporting, etc.